# How to get User Details in TFS Activity

Tags: tfs, msbuild, workflow-foundation-4

I wanted to get user details in my Execute Method.
I am using below code for this

```
[Description("Get User details.")]
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
public class UserInfo : CodeActivity
{
    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]        
    public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext contex)
    {
        IBuildDetail buildDetails = contex.GetValue(this.BuildDetail);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\test.txt",buildDetails.RequestedBy);

    }


}
```

I am trying to log activity output in file.
When i am passing RequestedBy to my activity as argument i am only getting domain user's name, but i also wanted his user name.

How can i get the complete details of user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS2013 and above,  in the new templates a lot of the complexity is hidden by default of builddetail. Try to use the **GetBuildDetail** activity to retrieve the variable you need.